# Algorithm for polynomial expansion without any CAS

Tags: python, polynomials

I'm looking for an algorithm to simplify polynomials like `x^2(2x^3-4(16x^4+20))`. My thoughts:

1. tokenize input string into list of classes "operator", "value"
2. build a binary tree where operators are non-terminated nodes (have children), and values are leaves.
3. try to simplify tree with math rules.

But I have trouble at almost every step:

- How to find tree's root?
- What to do with brackets?
- How to simplify tree and build string back?

Maybe there are other algorithms to solve my issue?

Comment: do you know [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)? otherwise it might be worth having a look at it... (ok that probably qualifies as CAS).

Comment: See section A Rule Language [here (pdf)](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/6064/AIM-986.pdf)